# Python boto3 download files from S3 error: "Connection broken: OSError"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

So, I am trying to download some files from a S3 bucket using  the python library boto3. The program worked, but encountered an error after downloaded 2 files ( i need to download about 30 files and the sizes of the files range from 100s Mb to around 1GB). I have been googling but have not yet find anything that can help me to solve this problem.

Below is what the error message says:

```
ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(10054, \'WSAECONNRESET\')")', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))
```

My program:

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session

bucket_name = '*********'
bucket_folder = '***/****/****/****'

session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id='************',
aws_secret_access_key='****************')

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for s3_file in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=bucket_folder):
    file_name = s3_file.key.split('/')[-1]
    print('Downloading file {} ...'.format(file_name))
    bucket.download_file(s3_file.key, file_name)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated, and please let me know if anything you would like me to clarify. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [The boto documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html) seems to recommend using a client rather than a session

Comment: The error message indicates a network error, rather than a coding error. Can you try it using a different network connection (eg home network, office network, tether via your phone, VPN connection)? You could instead use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which might offer better error-handling and retries.

Comment: I changed my code to use a client instead of session, but the same problem persists. Not sure about the AWS CLI though, I will read into it.